# MySQL Select Query taking long time to load

Tags: mysql

I am using below query for getting data from my mysql database, getting my expected result but it takes long time, almost 11 seconds to load :(

> Query

```
select 
    campaign_id,
    location_id,
    count(campaign_id) AS total_page_view,
    count(distinct client_mac) AS unique_visitors,
    (count(campaign_id) - count(distinct client_mac)) AS returning_users,
    sum((suid = 0)) AS bounce,
    concat(cast(((sum((suid = 0)) / count(campaign_id)) * 100)
                as decimal (10 , 2 )),
            '%') AS bounce_rate,
    created_at AS created_at
from
    social_user_device_info
group by campaign_id
order by cast(created_at as date) desc
limit 15
```

I have (~ 1,027,695 rows) records in my **social_user_device_info** table.

I need to fast load, what should i do?

Thanks

Comment: @devs, I have added campaign_id and created_at columns as index, but no luck.

Comment: show create statement for table `social_user_device_info`